# Installing Tomcat + Solr problem

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, ubuntu, solr

I'm trying to install Tomcat + Solr on my Ubuntu machine. I was using ubuntu repo:

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/intrepid/web/solr-tomcat5.5
http://packages.ubuntu.com/intrepid/tomcat5.5
```

When i launch tomcat, solr do not work:

```
sudo service tomcat5.5 start
```

The webpanel do not find solr, and give me this error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /solr/admin
```

Does anyone have any idea what this may be?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link usefully since i couldn't get nothing done from ubuntu repositories:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Simple_Example_Install

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu-packaged versions of Tomcat and Solr aren't known for working very well. I'd highly recommend going outside the package manager and getting them from the source. This guide should give you everything you need to know: http://justin-hayes.com/2009-04-08/installing-apache-tomcat-6-and-solr-nightly-on-ubuntu-804

Answer (score 0):

I was able to apt-get install tomcat6, and followed these directions:

https://wiki.fourkitchens.com/display/TECH/Solr+1.4+on+Ubuntu+9.10+and+CentOS+5

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to run Solr in an external container starting from version 5 . Support for deploying solr as a war in containers like Tomcat is no longer supported . It best works with the inbuilt Jetty Server with which it comes .Have a look at this link from Solr wiki documentation , it may clear your doubts https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+Tomcat .